# Accessing TFS cube to obtain area hierarchy's unique name

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, tfs, mdx

I would like to obtain the unique name of a given area path.

I've seen this article of John Socha: http://blogs.socha.com/2009/10/customizing-report-parameters-for-team.html. What I would like to do is to do in one query what John is doing manually.

I have a kind of "generic" query to obtain all the values of given area hierarchy level. The query is this:

```
    WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Work Item].[Area Hierarchy].CurrentMember.UniqueName
    MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Work Item].[Area Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal
    SELECT
    {
        [Measures].[ParameterValue],
        [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
    } ON COLUMNS,

    NON EMPTY { ([Work Item].[Area Hierarchy].[Area1].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
    ON ROWS 
    FROM [Team System]
```

With this query I obtain these values:
[image: Query's values]

So, it is possible that given an area path like \Tailspin Toys\Web Development obtain the unique name of the area in the TFS cube?

Thank you very much!

Best regards,

Vicenç

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict an MDX SELECT query using the WHERE clause. Add the following to the end of your query

```
WHERE [Work Item].[Item Hierarchy].[Tailspin Toys].[Web Development]
```